# Schrödinger equation: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{d}{dt}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, time, differentiation, notation

I have seen two different forms of Schrödinger equation:
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial|\psi(t)\rangle}{\partial t}=\hat{H}|\psi(t)\rangle$$
and
$$i\hbar\frac{d|\psi(t)\rangle}{d t}=\hat{H}|\psi(t)\rangle.$$

Are these two equations equivalent? If not, in what situations are each equation used?

Comment: When you write the abstract ket $|\psi(t)\rangle$ there is a single variable, so $d/dt$ would be appropriate. When you project onto the position basis you construct the wavefunction $\psi(t,x)=\langle x|\psi(t)\rangle$ and so, when writing the equation in position representation, you have more than one variable, so that $\partial/\partial t$ would be appropriate.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/367750/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. Strictly speaking the second one is correct, because the state vector is a function only of time, but physicists aren't always very careful about distinguishing partial vs single-variable derivatives. The partial derivative might have stuck because as an analogy to the wavefunction $\psi(x,t)$, for which a partial derivative is appropriate.