# What's the time derivative of the Annihilation operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

I've been dealing with annihilation operator recently where you can see related information

- [Time derivative of the state vector as expressed in abstract Hilbert space vs. as a wavefunction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113295/)
- [How to get the time derivative of an expectation value in quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128276/)

and

- ["Creation and annihilation operators"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators), Wikipedia

for definition.

Correction made by Valter Moretti and J.G.'s answer, there is no contradiction.

$$
\begin{align}
i \hbar \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left(a \left| \psi(n,t) \right\rangle \right)
& ~=~ i \hbar \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left(\sqrt{n} \left| \psi(n-1,t) \right\rangle \right) \\[5px]
& ~=~ H \sqrt{n} \left| \psi(n-1,t) \right\rangle \\[5px]
& ~=~ E_{n-1}\sqrt{n} \left| \psi(n-1,t) \right\rangle
\end{align}
\,.$$

and
\begin{align}
i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}(a|\psi(n,t)\rangle)
& =i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}(a)|\psi(n,t)\rangle+a(i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|\psi(n,t)\rangle) \\[5px]
& =i\hbar \cdot iwa|\psi(n,t)\rangle+a(H|\psi(n,t)\rangle) \\[5px]
& =-\hbar w a|\psi(n,t)\rangle+a(E_n|\psi(n,t)\rangle) \\[5px]
& =(E_n-\hbar w)a|\psi(n,t)\rangle\\[5px]
& =E_{n-1} a|\psi(n,t)\rangle\\[5px]
& =E_{n-1} \sqrt{n}|\psi(n-1,t)\rangle
\end{align}

Notice $\frac{d}{dt}(a)\neq 0$ despite the fact that $a$ in matrix represtation is a constant matrix.

Comment: Surely the error is assuming $\dot{a}=0$; comparing the two calculations lets you compute $\dot{a}$. You could try writing $a$ as an outer product as well.

Comment: The former is wrong. It is false that $a\psi_n(t) = \sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1}(t)$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Could you explain a bit?

Comment: @J.G. But $a$ is $a$ acturally fixed in matrix represtation, you can find it in wiki.

Comment: $a\psi_n(t)= e^{-iE_nt} a\psi_n$. Compute the derivative...

Comment: Or also, directly: $a\psi_n(t)= e^{-iE_nt} a\psi_n=\sqrt{n} e^{-iE_nt} \psi_{n-1}$. Compare with your identity. Is the right hand side $\sqrt{n} \psi_{n-1}(t)$?

Comment: @ValterMoretti According to your definition $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}a\psi_n(t)=\hbar E_n a \psi_n(t)$, I mean, the unit doesn't seem correct. the right hand side should be just energy not not $\hbar$ times energy.

Comment: $\sqrt{n} \psi_{n-1}(t)=\sqrt{n} e^{-iE_{n-1}t} \psi_{n-1}$.

Comment: I am assuming $\hbar =1$. It has no relevance in this issue however...

Comment: However, regarding your problem, the crucial observation is that **$a$ does not commute with the evolutor operator since it does not commute with $H$**.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thank you, but doesn't $a|\psi_n>=\sqrt{n}|\psi_{n-1}>$? also I haven't used any commutative relation during the derivation. But for your expression, if one applie $a$ of $n$ times to ground states, the ground state's evoluation followed the evoluation of level $n$? I mean use quantum postulate, once the energy changes, the measurement of $H$ changes, and therefore the time evoluation changes.

Comment: The identity you wrote is true for $t=0$. You used (false) commutativity of $a$ and the time evolutor when you extended that identity to $t>0$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi(x,E_n,t)>=H|\psi(x,E_n,t)>$ and does not concern $x,t$ or $E_n$. It's postulate.

Comment: Please focus on what I wrote instead of trying to find ways out. You are missing a crucial fact. The problem with your wrong derivation is that I pointed out.

Comment: @ValterMoretti can you put it in an answer?

Comment: Ok I will do later. Bye

Comment: @ValterMoretti Than you. I think I got what you are saying, but then secound thoughts if $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}a|psi(n,t)>=E_n \sqrt{n}...$ which seemed to indicate $a$ did not change the energy states of the system.

Comment: @ValterMoretti I figured it out. you and J.G. were both right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your **first** answer is the identity (I prefer to  modify notations)
$$a \psi_n(t) = \sqrt{n} \psi_{n-1}(t)\:.\quad (false \:\:if \:\:t\neq 0)\tag{1}$$
This is false if $t\neq 0$ (it is trivially true for  $n=0$, but I assume $n\neq 0$ henceforth).

Since $\psi(t) :=  e^{-itH/\hbar} \psi$, the identity above can be expanded as 
$$a e^{-itH/\hbar} \psi_n = \sqrt{n}   e^{-itH/\hbar} \psi_{n-1} \quad(false \:\:if \:\:t\neq 0)\:.$$
In fact, both sides can be separately computed,
$$a e^{-itH/\hbar} \psi_n =  a e^{-itE_n/\hbar} \psi_n= e^{-itE_n/\hbar} a\psi_n= e^{-itE_n/\hbar} \sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1} =  \sqrt{n}e^{-itE_n/\hbar} \psi_{n-1} $$
whereas 
$$\sqrt{n}   e^{-itH/\hbar} \psi_{n-1} = \sqrt{n} e^{-itE_{n-1}/\hbar} \psi_{n-1}\:,$$
and
$$\sqrt{n}e^{-itE_n/\hbar} \psi_{n-1} \neq \sqrt{n} e^{-itE_{n-1}/\hbar} \psi_{n-1}$$
because 
$$E_n\neq E_{n-1}\:.$$
The fundamental reason of the failure of (1) is that  $a$ and $e^{-itH/\hbar}$ do not commute. It it were 
$$a e^{-itH/\hbar} = e^{-itH/\hbar} a\:,$$
then we would have
$$\langle \psi_n |a e^{-itH/\hbar}\psi_m \rangle  = \langle \psi_n | e^{-itH/\hbar} a \psi_m\rangle$$
i.e.
$$\langle a^*\psi_n | e^{-itH/\hbar}\psi_m \rangle  = \langle e^{itH/\hbar}\psi_n |  a \psi_m\rangle\:.$$
taking the time derivative for  $t=0$,
$$\langle a^*\psi_n | H\psi_m \rangle  = \langle H\psi_n |  a \psi_m\rangle\:,$$
so that
$$\langle \psi_n | aH\psi_m \rangle  = \langle \psi_n |  Ha \psi_m\rangle\:,$$
so that 
$$\langle \psi_n | (aH-Ha)\psi_m \rangle  = 0$$
namely, since the Hermite functions $\psi_n$ span a dense space, 
$$aH\psi_m= Ha\psi_m\:.$$
By linearity, we would have
$$aH= Ha\:.$$
at least restricting the domains to  the span of Hermite functions $\psi_n$. The identity above is false in view of the commutation relations of $a$ and $a^*$ and $H = \hbar \omega (a^*a + I/2)$ over the said space.

Coming back to your question, the correct result  is the second one.

Comment: Thank you. Up vote. However, still one little question. If the time derivative of the function returned $E_n$, does that mean $a|\psi(n,t)>$ is still in energy states $E_n$? because $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}a|\psi(n,t)>=Ha|\psi(n,t)>=E_na|\psi(n,t)>$? So what's $a$'s effect to the states $a|\psi(n,t)>$?

Comment: No, $a\psi_n(t)$ has no longer  energy $E_n$. Indeed, as a state, it has energy $E_{n-1}$ like $\psi_{n-1}$. The only difference is a factor: $a\psi_n(t) = e^{-i(E_{n-1}-E_n)t/\hbar}\sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1}$. So, there is an evident effect of the action of $a$, it changes the energy.

Comment: Can you clearfy a little? Because, if $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}$ act on a states and return $E_n$ and that states, it's the same as $H$ act on that sates and obtained energy $E_n$ by the postulate right? So on one side I think I got your point, but on the other side your asnwer didn't seem to give the correct energy states.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you are saying. $d/dt$ acts on a function of $t$ taking values in the Hilbert space and produces a similar function. It is not an operator as $H$ is,  which insteads works on a single vector and produces a vector. What it is clear it is what I wrote, $a\psi_n(t)$ is an eigenvector of $H$ with eigenvalue $E_{n-1}$ instead of $E_n$.

Comment: $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi>=H|\psi>=E|\psi>$, so if $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi>=E_2|\psi>$, that $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}$ returned the same funciton, then by equality and right cancellation, the coefficient $E_1=E_2$. So if by taking the derivative one obtained the same function and $E_n$, then it's in energy states $E_n$. So far your answer return the same funciton by applying $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}$, yet it has not been able to return the correct energy states $E_{n-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand. However, you wrote $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}a \psi_n(t)= Ha \psi_n(t)$. But it is false. What it is true is $i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}a \psi_n(t)= aH \psi_n(t)$...

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful not to mix up implications specific to different pictures. For example, $\partial_t\langle m|a|n\rangle$ doesn't imply $\dot{a}=0$ in the Heisenberg picture because $|n,\,t\rangle=\exp -i\omega_n t|n,\,0\rangle,\,\omega_n:=\frac{E_n}{\hbar}$. While $\dot{a}=0$ in the Schrödinger picture, it can be shown $\dot{a}=-i\omega a$ in the Heisenberg picture, where the Hamiltonian is $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\partial_x^2+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x^2$. I'll give two proofs; there are plenty of others.

The first is one I mentioned in a comment: since $\partial_t|n\rangle=-i\omega_n|n\rangle$ and $a=\sum_{n\ge 1}\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle\langle n|$, $\dot{a}=-i(\omega_n-\omega_{n-1})a=-i\omega a$.

Another approach uses $\dot{x}=\frac{p}{m},\,\dot{p}=-m\omega^2 x,\,a=\frac{m\omega x+ip}{\sqrt{2m\hbar\omega}}$.

Comment: $a$ does **not**  depend on time here, we are dealing with Schroedinger picture here. What you wrote makes sense in Heisenberg picture.

Comment: @ValterMoretti I've added a picture discussion in case the OP had overlooked it too.

Comment: Ok, now what you wrote is correct, but I do not think that it answers OP's question.